# Flag effect in opengl

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to follow this online tutorial to create some waves
http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/flag_effect_(waving_texture)/16002/.

I want to make the wave much bigger, but I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way, the current mesh of quads is sized 45 in the tutorial, so i have increased to 450, however the size doesn't seem to increase that much.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what needs to be modified to make the quads bigger.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly should be bigger. Amplitude or frequency of waves? Number of quads? Their size?

Comment: The size of the quads, so the water area is greater

Comment: Just scale it with `glScalef` after rotations.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the quads bigger, then you need to modify the vertex position code. In the NeHe tutorial you posted change this part:

```
// Loop Through The X Plane
for(int x=0; x<45; x++)
{
    // Loop Through The Y Plane
    for(int y=0; y<45; y++)
    {
        // Apply The Wave To Our Mesh
        points[x][y][0]=float((x/5.0f)-4.5f);
        points[x][y][1]=float((y/5.0f)-4.5f);
        points[x][y][2]=float(sin((((x/5.0f)*40.0f)/360.0f)*3.141592654*2.0f));
    }
}
```

To this:

```
// Loop Through The X Plane
float spacing = 0.5f;
float spacingInv = 1.0f/spacing;
float offset = (45 / spacingInv) / 2.0f;    // The 45 comes from the number of points (if you change this, change the for loop and the variable creation)
for(int x=0; x<45; x++)
{
    // Loop Through The Y Plane
    for(int y=0; y<45; y++)
    {
        // Apply The Wave To Our Mesh
        // We change the x/5.0f-4.5f to change the size of the quads
        // See text after for more details
        points[x][y][0]=float((x/spacingInv)-offset);
        points[x][y][1]=float((y/spacingInv)-offset);
        points[x][y][2]=float(sin((((x/spacingInv)*40.0f)/360.0f)*3.141592654*2.0f));
    }
}
```

Explanation: 
x/5.0f gives you values 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, ......, 9.0.

If you were to take just those values, you would now have an off center grid of quads. Now taking x/5.0f - 4.5f gives you values -4.5 -4.3, -4.1, ...... 4.1, 4.3, 4.5

If you wanted to make the quads bigger, you need to increase the spacing between the points (i.e. change the x/5.0f to something like x/2.0f (which is what happens in the example I gave)). And then you want to recenter (i.e. change the -4.5f).